# How to access git repository whilst using brew command?

Tags: ssh, github, brew

I am trying to install a package using brew but it is asking for Github username and password and failing to authenticate the connection even though I have added the ssh key to the Github. Can you suggest a way to fix this issue? Here's the response in terminal:

```
fam007e@DarkKnightz:~$ brew tap owasp-amss/amass
Running `brew update --auto-update`...
==> Tapping owasp-amss/amass
Cloning into '/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Homebrew/Library/Taps/owasp-amss/homebrew-amass'...
Username for 'https://github.com': fam007e
Password for 'https://fam007e@github.com': 
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.
remote: Please see https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently recommended modes of authentication.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/owasp-amss/homebrew-amass/'
Error: Failure while executing; `git clone https://github.com/owasp-amss/homebrew-amass /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Homebrew/Library/Taps/owasp-amss/homebrew-amass --origin=origin --template= --config core.fsmonitor=false` exited with 128.
fam007e@DarkKnightz:~$ ssh -T git@github.com
Hi fam007e! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Comment: Did you check the link provided, as for Github you need to have a "Personal access Token" instead of a passwd.

Comment: @admstg @marcus-müller so would it be like this: ```brew untap owasp/amass
brew tap https://<PAT>@github.com/owasp/amass.git
 ```

Answer (score 1):

That repo is not publicly acessible. If you have private access when you're logged in:

Please read the link provided in the error message, it does explain what there is to do (namely, log in, get an access token, and use that for your git).